# Определение схожих вопросов

Tags: python, анализ

Задача состоит в том, что нужно вести учет схожих, по смыслу, вопросов к роботу. Я читал об алгоритмах и способах анализа двух текстов на схожесть, но все они ориентированы именно на тексты, занимающие хотя бы пару абзацев. В моем же случае вопрос может состоять и из трех слов. Под схожестью подразумевается то, что два вопроса ниже имеют один смысл, значит схожи:

```
до скольки работает магазин? 
когда закрывается магазин?
```

В идеальном варианте с предыдущими двумя схож еще и вопрос:

```
до скольки можно посетить ваш магазин?
```

Сам смотрел в сторону:

- канонизации вопросов (убирая слова по типу "ли", "то", "ну" и приводя оставшиеся слова по принципу "работает" -> "работать") - так себе результат показывает
- определения схожести вопросов по наличию ключевых слов.
- подбор синонимов (для определения того, что используется слово с одной смысловой нагрузкой) - не всегда подбирается одно слово.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет в какую сторону смотреть и поделится собственным опытом в этой сфере. Делается это все на python.

Comment: учить нужно в сторону [Machine Learning](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Но вот только работы тут - делать не переделать.

Comment: дурацкое предложение - раз вопросы адресуются роботу, может быть выделить среди всей массы набор самых популярных и задавать их, выбирая из готового списка? а для тех вопросов, которые в списке отсутствуют, показывать текстовое поле, куда можно писать?